# Problem with the size of my Facebook App

Tags: css, facebook

I'm having some problem with the size of my Facebook iframe App, I can't actually look the iframe in the size that I want.

I have the CSS of my page with the height set in auto but in the iframe of facebook it doesn't look the correct size. I also put in the settings of my APP the iframe to Auto-resize but nothing.

```
<iframe class="canvas_iframe_util" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe_canvas" name="iframe_canvas" src='javascript:""'></iframe>
```

This is the code of my facebook iframe, but then I checked the code of another application and I saw that they have the height defined just like that:

```
<iframe class="canvas_iframe_util noresize" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe_canvas" name="iframe_canvas" src='javascript:""' style="height: 1420px; overflow-y: hidden; "></iframe>
```

The point is that I don't know how to do that or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: the height defined in the second example is a pixel value, not auto?

Comment: This might be a repeat of [Auto-Fit iFrame Height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972598/auto-fit-iframe-height/5983850).

Answer (score 0):

You need the simple script

```
<script>
    var obj = new Object;
    obj.width = 1000;
    obj.height = 1700;
    FB.Canvas.setSize(obj);
</script>
```

colocate before the close html: "</html>"